# VS 2008 SP1 can't deploy on MC9200 with Windows CE 7.0

Tags: visual-studio-2008, windows-ce, rpc, barcode-scanner

Whenever I try to deploy solution to above mentioned device I'm getting error:

```
Connection Failed. The RPC Server is unavailable.
```

[image]

I tried the solutions from following link, but no help: https://www.auslogics.com/en/articles/fixing-the-rpc-server-is-unavailable-error-in-windows/

Windows Mobile Device Center says device is connected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to dig up an old email (June 2012) which gives some instructions I sent to my team:

1. Install Microsoft® Visual Studio 2008 with Service Pack1 (make sure you have the service pack)
2. Install the update that adds support for Windows Embedded Compact 7.0 - http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2483802
3. Install the update that extends support for Windows Embedded Compact 7.0 - http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2468183
4. Download and install the Platform SDK - https://www.zebra.com/us/en/support-downloads/software/developer-tools/MC9200-platform-sdk.html
5. Run the EMDK Integrator for the new platform SDK

Comment: Not sure how step 5 is performed, but it worked. Thank you very much!

Comment: The Microsoft download links no longer work. Any idea where I can find these updates - specifically 2468183 (I've got the others).

Comment: I checked my ISO backup and I'm afraid I never kept a copy of these.  Can't find them online either.  I presume MS removed them because extended support for CE ended but that does not explain why the original articles would remain up.