# visual studio including device SDK

Tags: .net, visual-studio

I am working with the Zebra MK3100 kiosk and I am working with Visual Studio attempting to make an app. 
I read that using VS Device simulator I can include my products SDK in order to get a simulator that looks like mine. However i'm not really sure how to do that. Initially I thought I didn't have the proper drivers for the device, but I checked with Zebra and it appears I have downloaded everything that is required, which is the EMDK. Am I supposed to do something else on Visual studio I try loading the Windows CE device and I get `connection failed. The bootstrap could not be loaded.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The MK3100 is a CE7 device.  You can't use the simulators that come with Visual Studio 2008 for development on Zebra (formally Symbol or Motorola Solutions) devices as the EMDK interfaces with the physical scanning hardware.

I detailed the steps to get CE7 development going in a previous post about MC9200 [VS 2008 SP1 can't deploy on MC9200 with Windows CE 7.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54075304/vs-2008-sp1-cant-deploy-on-mc9200-with-windows-ce-7-0/54105188#54105188), essentially the steps were:

1. Install VS2008 and all service packs
2. Install 2 components from Microsoft to allow connection to CE7
3. Install 2 components from Microsoft to allow connection to CE7
4. Download and install the 'Platform SDK' (I think that is what you are talking about in your question but it does not include simulators)
5. Run the EMDK Integrator to add EMDK functionality to the Platform SDK.

There are a couple of problems with the above steps now though when I revisit the answer.  Firstly, I can't find the MK3100 platform SDK available for download anywhere but that is not too problematic as you can use the MC9200 platform SDK and everything will still work.

More of an issue is that the 2 Microsoft components are no longer available, presumably because MS support for CE7 has ceased.  As far as I remember you need those two MS packages to get your machine to connect to the device via ActiveSync or Device Centre.

Hope that helps, it's been a few years since I developed for CE7.  You may also need to use Win7 as I have never tried doing so on Win10

Comment: Thank you, this is a pretty old device and I was having a hard time getting my environment setup because something was always missing. Now that I have you here and you have been very helpful, I am running into some issues when it comes to connecting to my DB from my device. Did you by any chance work on that with the MC9200 Device?

Comment: also will the steps you mentioned above will they give me a simulation or will they allow me to connect to the device?

Comment: The DB question is quite open ended and I never personally developed a DB orientated application but if you search for 'wince' or (less usefully) 'ce' along with the search term you usually get some good hits, e.g. wince database brings up some MS threads.  You could develop your app in a simulator (though, those MS components are no longer available for download that I can see) but real development with the scanner needs to be on-device.